# Ember computed property for hiding element

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm trying to get an element in ember to be hidden (set class with `display: hidden;`) depending on the presence of a certain element in a controller property. I also have two other computed properties in the view, one is rowNumber and the other columnNumber. Those two properties work as expected but when I add code into the hiddenClass computed property, the code breaks and claims that "Something you did caused a view to re-render after it was rendered but before the element was added into DOM".

The code for the computed property is:

```
hiddenClass: function() {
        var cells = this.get('controller.occupiedCells');
        console.log('onOccupiedChange fired');
        var r = cells.filterBy('row',parseInt(this.get('rowNumber'))).findProperty('col',parseInt(this.get('columnNumber')));
    }.property('controller.occupiedCells.@each')
```

I am aware that this doesn't return true/false as expected, nonetheless no exception is thrown if I remove the line declaring `var r`. How do I get the element to be hidden when a condition that depends on rowNumber and columnNumber is met?

Comment: what does your template look like?

Comment: [Always use a radix when using `parseInt`](http://www.michaelgaigg.com/blog/2008/10/07/the-importance-of-the-javascript-parseint-radix/).

Comment: `<tr id="row-3">
        <th>8:30 am</th>
        {{#each a in model.arr}}
            {{view "droppable-cell"}}
        {{/each}}
        <td class="expand"></td>
    </tr>`
Is the one that refers to the view, the views template is:
`{{#if view.objectExample}}
{{draggable-object-example objectExample=view.objectExample isPlaced=true}}
{{/if}}`

Comment: It shouldn't matter though because the templates all render perfectly until the line where r is declared and initialized is added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out to be that the line:

`var r = cells.filterBy('row',parseInt(this.get('rowNumber'))).findProperty('col',parseInt(this.get('columnNumber')));`

was using `get` on computed properties which had jQuery code in them, since jQuery code should not be run before the element has been inserted into the DOM I was getting the error about re-rendering. I was able to fix the issue by overriding the didInsertElement method to postpone any evaluation of jQuery until after the element had been appended to the DOM.